# Action of $SO(4)$ on $M$ that is transitive

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions

I am trying to find a transitive left action of $SO(4)$ on the set $\mathcal{P}$ of oriented 2-planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Each element in $P$ in $\mathcal{P}$ is a 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be represented as a equivalence class of pairs of orthonormal vectors $(v_1,v_2)$ where $(v_1,v_2)\sim (w_1,w_2)$ iff they are related by an element of $SO(4)$.

I think the left action of $A\in SO(4)$ on $[(v,w)]\in \mathcal{P}$ should be defined by $$A\cdot [(v,w)]=[(Av,Aw)].$$ And I think I should show that for any $[(v_1,v_2)],[(w_1,w_2)]\in \mathcal{P}$, we should have $A\in \mathcal{P}$ such that $A\cdot [(v_1,v_2)]=[(w_1,w_2)]$ and naturally( I believe ), $(Av_2,Av_2)=(w_1,w_2)$.  Can we build such matrix in terms of $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2$?

Any explanation would be very thankful.

I am very new to Geometry so it is possible that I made a mistake even in defining the action. So please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you can build it from $v_1,v_2,w_1,w_2$, although it is actually more revealing when you know the isomorphism $\def\Spin{\operatorname{Spin}} \Spin(4)\cong\Spin(3)\times\Spin(3)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the action is correct. This is a transitive action, because given $[(v_1,v_2)]$ and $[(w_1,w_2)]$ in $\mathcal{P}$, you may complete $(v_1,v_2)$ and $(w_1,w_2)$ to positive orthonormal bases of $\Bbb R^4$: $$(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)\quad\mbox{and}\quad(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4).$$This way, by construction we have that the linear map $A$ satisfying $Av_i = w_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$ is in ${\rm SO}(4)$, and we have $A\cdot [(v_1,v_2)] = [(w_1,w_2)]$. The map $A$ is not unique -- indeed, you have the freedom of applying counter-clockwise rotations in the $2$-plane normal to $[(v_1,v_2)]$. So, if you want an explicit map $A$, you need to make a choice of basis completion for both $(v_1,v_2)$ and $(w_1,w_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there really no way to represent such a matrix in terms of $v_i$ and $w_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: If you have fixed $v_3,v_4,w_3$ and $w_4$, of course there is. Call the first base $\mathcal{B}$ and the second one $\mathcal{C}$. By definition, $[A]_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}} = {\rm Id}_4$. Now you can compute the matrix of $A$ with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^4$ using stuff you have seen in any linear algebra course (change of basis, etc).

Comment: Then, how do we know that such a matrix is in $SO(4)$?

Comment: Because it takes a positive orthonormal basis into another one (by construction!!!) -- trying to do computations with $a_{ij}$ in terms of arbitrary given vectors is madness.

Comment: I searched for a while but I could not find the definition of positive orthonormal basis? Could you define it for me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)

Comment: Now I get it ! Thank you!

Comment: I want to stress a comment Ivo made above.  In many of these kinds of problems, you want to avoid any kind of serious computation.  You do not want to verify a matrix is orthogonal by computating $AA^t$ and hoping for the identity.  You typically want to understand the definitions geometrically, e.g. $AA^t = Id$ iff the columns of $A$ form an orthonormal basis iff A maps the standard basis vectors to an orthonormal basis iff $A$ preserves all lengths and angles.